# Angularjs $animate promises css keyframe animations

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate, angular-promise

According to the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate/service/$animate) (emphasis mine):

> With AngularJS 1.3, each of the animation methods, on the $animate service, return a promise when called. The promise itself is then **resolved once the animation has completed itself**, has been cancelled or has been skipped due to animations being disabled.

Whilst `$animate` is returning a promise, it seems to resolve instantly.

To demonstrate, I've created a simple [example in codepen](http://codepen.io/redders6600/pen/mydryv)

Here is the relevant script (on click):

```
$elem = angular.element('<div class="donkey">Not resolved</div>')

$animate.enter($elem, element).then(
  $elem.html('My promise is resolved!') 
)
```

And style:

```
.donkey
  &.ng-enter
    animation(2s,slide)

@keyframes slide
  from
    transform translateX(20rem)
    opacity 0
  to
    transform translateX(0)
    opacity 1
```

#### Expected:

On clicking the button, the element should be added to the DOM, then should slide into view with the text `Not resolved`. **As soon as the animation finishes** the text should update to `My promise is resolved`.

#### Actual:

The element is added to the DOM, and the animation is successfully triggered, but **the promise resolves instantly** so the text reads `My promise is resolved` whilst the animation is executing.

What am I doing wrong? Can you create a fork of the plunker where this works (without using `$timeout` or similar)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current CoffeeScript compiles to this:

```
return scope.enter = function() {
  var $elem;
  $elem = angular.element('<div class="donkey">Not resolved</div>');
  return $animate.enter($elem, element).then($elem.html('My promise is resolved!'));
};
```

Note that it is not a function that gets passed to `then`, but instead the instantly executed result of `$elem.html('My promise is resolved!')`. And since it executes instantly the HTML will change before the promise is resolved.

It should be:

```
$animate.enter($elem, element).then(->
  $elem.html('My promise is resolved!')
)
```

And the last part will compile to:

```
return $animate.enter($elem, element).then(function() {
  return $elem.html('My promise is resolved!');
});
```

And if you don't want the `return` in the compiled code:

```
$animate.enter($elem, element).then(->
  $elem.html('My promise is resolved!')
  return
)
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OPJpzV

Comment: Absolutely right, missing `() - >` was a typo on my part.  Somehow I repeated it when I made the codepen too! Thanks